# The distribution of means from gamma-distribution doesn't match theoretical values in Python

Tags: python-3.x, probability-density, probability-theory

I do an assignment for a certain course on Coursera. The whole point is to use central limit theorem for some distribution (I chose Gamma-distribution) and plot on diagram theoretical values for probability density function of normal distribution with E = Ebase and D = Dbase/n, where E and D are math expectation and dispersion of the distribution of means.

The means are taken from the samples of size n, where each unit is generated by Gamma-distribution with manually inserted parameters (I use `k = 2`, `theta = 0.5`) and thus `Ebase = k*theta` and `Dbase = k*theta^2`.  On the same diagram there should be a histogram normed to 1.

Theoretically the greater n we take the more matched two graphics should be. But I have it like this in ipython notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats as sts
%matplotlib inline
k = 2.0
Theta = 0.5
listOfSizes = [20,50,100,300]
number = 0
for n in listOfSizes:
    means =[]
    for i in range (1000):
       sum = 0.0
       for number in np.random.gamma(k,Theta,size = n):
           sum+=number
       mean = sum/n
       means.append(mean)
dispersionOfMeansTheoretical =(k*(Theta**2))/n
mathExpectancyOfMeansTheoretical = (k*Theta)
arguments = np.linspace(0,2,2048)
plt.figure(n)
theoryFunction = sts.norm.pdf(arguments, loc = mathExpectancyOfMeansTheoretical, scale = dispersionOfMeansTheoretical)
plt.plot(arguments, theoryFunction)
plt.hist(means, bins=50, normed = 1)
plt.ylabel('$PDF$ with n ='+str(n))
plt.xlabel('$x$')
```

[image: Graphics]

I double-checked it on Wiki, and it seems like I insert the right parametrization for everything but I really can't find a mistake. What have I missed?

Comment: Please replace your screenshot of code with actual text. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code for more information.

Comment: `dispersionOfMeansTheoretical` is the variance. The pdf argument `scale` takes the standard deviation - just replace it with `np.sqrt(dispersionOfMeansTheoretical)` and it should work.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, thank you! It worked! For some reason i thought it was variance not standard devitaion that it takes as an argument.